# Do we call a 2/3 year old child a baby?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

[This website](https://www.verywellfamily.com/difference-between-baby-newborn-infant-toddler-293848#:%7E:text=When%20Is%20a%20Baby%20Considered,walk%20or%20one%20who%20toddles.) says

> Baby can be used to refer to any child from birth to age 4 years old,
> thus encompassing newborns, infants, and toddlers.

How do native English speakers use "**baby**" in everyday English?

**Do we call a 2/3 year old child a baby?**

Comment: That website says _The exact definition depends on the source you consult._ I would add _and on the context_. **Baby** usually implies an infant who doesn't walk yet, but in some contexts it might mean a pre-school child - 'babies and children'. (Incidentally, the literal meaning of _infant_ is 'unable to speak', but in England we call children in their first few years at school 'infants'!)

Comment: [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/baby) says "a very young child, especially one that has not yet begun to walk or talk". That could apply to a 4 year old, but probably not. Baby is commonly used as a term of endearment for older children, but less so in a medical context. And note for instance that in some legal contexts "[infancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infant)" means under 18, so there is a lot of variation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site you linked to says:

> The English language has several terms for children between the ages
> of birth and 4 years, including newborn, infant, baby, and toddler.
> These terms are often used interchangeably for various ages of young
> children and may mean different things to different people.

Thus the age range during which 'baby' is appropriate is a matter of opinion. A child aged 12 months is definitely a 'baby'; one of 36 months is, perhaps, still a baby but more likely to be called a 'toddler'. If pressed, I would concede that, in my opinion, a toddler is a kind of big, walking, talking baby, and that a child of 48 months is no longer a baby.